# Prevent Persistent Database Connections from RStudio

Tags: r, postgresql, docker, odbc, rstudio

I have a Redshift database and I run RStudio inside of a Docker Image substantiated from Jupyter Notebooks.

I added ODBC drivers and installed the `odbc` package as part of the command to spin up the Docker instance.

My concern is that I end up having too many open connections with the database.

I'm concerned about having many long lived connections because they might lock up my tables. I looked through the docs for odbc and RPostgreSQL and I didn't see anything about a time-out or a way to clear all connections.

How can I prevent having too many long lived connections from RStudio to PostgreSQL?

Comment: It depends on the app and on the server configuration. If the app does not close connections when needed, does not do sufficient `tryCatch` and/or `on.exit` work to ensure that connections are in the intended state, then things can "dangle". If the server keeps the R process running the app alive too long, then the app with many connections can stay around too long. You might consider the `pool` package, though it is not an adequate replacement for connection management.

Comment: Great! Your description of a database that allows things to dangle is accurate. Can I use `pool` along with `odbc`?

Comment: Yes, the arguments you give to `pool` are passed directly to whichever (`DBI`) driver you prefer to use, `odbc` among them. (I use that combo every day.)

Comment: Great! Would you like to add that as an answer so I can mark it correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My preference and solution has been to use the [`pool`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pool/index.html) package for managing connections. I've not needed to have a large "pool" of connections to benefit from one of its capabilities: reconnect on timeout.

Use is simple-enough. Similar to most other `DBI` drivers, you don't need to `library(pool)`, just refer to it on opening.

If your original open call is:

```r
library(DBI)
con <- dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), driver = "ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server",
                 server = "somehost,1433", uid = "someuser", pwd = "secret",
                 database = "umptysquat")
```

Then instead use:

```r
con <- pool::dbPool(odbc::odbc(), driver = "ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server",
                    server = "somehost,1433", uid = "someuser", pwd = "secret",
                    database = "umptysquat", minSize = 1, maxSize = 5)
```

(replacing meaningful numbers for `minSize` and `maxSize`). From here, `DBI::dbGetQuery(con, "select 1 as a")` works as if it were real. For me, one of the real benefits is that when the connection is closed (for any reason, including timeout and my ssh tunnel breaks down), the pool connection auto-reconnects on the next query.

Most functions work as-is, though occasionally (I cannot recall or reproduce at this moment) I've had to do `library(pool);library(odbc)` for some DBI functions. Again, can't recall, it might be something unrelated. Loading them is generally not a problem (I just prefer to not attach too many packages if I can avoid it).

Comment: I un-marked this as complete because it doesn't solve the problem. It turns out that RStudio gets loaded in separate Docker images, so `pool` won't work.

Comment: Is it possible to add a time-out period to database connections?

Comment: https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/pool-advanced.html suggests `idleTimeout=`

Comment: and `odbc` itself takes a `timeout=` argument, https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/odbc/odbc.pdf

Comment: Great! The `odbc` timeout appears to work for cases where there's a slow connection to the database `Time in seconds to timeout the connection attempt.  Setting a timeout ofInfindicates no timeout. (defaults to 10 seconds).`

Comment: Often, connection keepalive/timeout is controlled by the server, either authoritatively or in addition to the client. One could always set up a small db-"ping", `observe({ invalidateLater(30000); DBI::dbGetQuery(con, "select 1"); })` (for a 30-sec query), but if done poorly this might have an effect on the app (and defeat the whole reason for connection termination on lack of activity).